API Gateway custom authorizer response message and status code
"How do I set the status code to 406 and return a custom message from an API Gateway custom authorizer? The same question has already been asked here:old question"
I have searched, but I still didn't find an answer.

You can always setup the custom message and status code inside the lambda function associated with the API Gateway resources. Why do you need to setup this through API Gateway?

@Cylian How can we set up a custom message and status code inside the Lambda authorizer itself? Could you provide a sample code?

You may follow the link below to solve your problem...
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html
The documentation link contains useful resources and codes which will help you to prepare your customized lambda function.
